# App goes very slow when "filereplacements" implementing in angular.json in angular ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-native, ionic6

When I change the environments configuration in angular.json,

```
"customer1-dev": {
            "fileReplacements": [
                {
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/environment.customer1.ts"
                }
            ],
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "optimization": false,
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "namedChunks": true
            
        },
```

When I add '**fileReplacements**' in the configuration, my app run very slow.

and when I remove the '**fileReplacements**' then app run faster.

I had create a environment setup for the different-2 customer with the same app source-code.
[Reference URL](https://medium.com/@akashjadhav.dev/multiple-environments-client-specific-app-build-in-ionic-4-5bc5ad39ddc)
That's why I need to setup configuration in angular.json.

**Environment setup for customer specific, is working fine but app run very slow.**

Comment: can you include all of the configurations inside angular.json? if you're trying to run production settings e.g. `optimization: true` during development it will be slow. A development config may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Typical development config:

```json
{
    "configurations": {
        ...
        // can change "development" to any configuration target
        "development": {
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "optimization": false,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": true,
          "fileReplacements": [...]
        }
}
```

By not optimising the dev server is faster. Obviously you'll need a separate production config to get an optimised build.

Comment: Yes, I also try this but still run very slow.

Comment: Yeah, just saw update to your post. Not sure. As far as I know fileReplacements runs only once so the app being slow doesn't make sense